# Sidekiq queue failing in test - requires separate Redis process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Running an RSpec test with a Sidekiq::Queue instance is failing unless Redis is running separately.

```
Sidekiq::Queue.new('my-queue').select(&:item)
```

Raises error in test

```
Redis::CannotConnectError:
   Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

I've added the usual to the spec helper:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```

And `mock_redis` to the gemfile.

```
# gemfile
gem 'mock_redis', '0.16.1'
```

Using `sidekiq (3.4.2)`

How can I update my configuration to allow this to work?

Comment: Define "fails in tests"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev updated question. It raises a `Redis::CannotConnectError`

Comment: Do you pass the mocked redis to sidekiq in tests? It doesn't work automagically.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just figured out a solution and posted that answer below. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Nope, not really.

Comment: The API does not provide a fake version by design.

Answer (score 1):

`mock_redis` only provides with a fake redis. It does not intercept/replace actual redis classes/connections. If you intend to use fake redis in tests, you should tell sidekiq so. In your `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` (or whereever your sidekiq redis config is):

```
redis = if Rails.env.test?
  require 'mock_redis'
  MockRedis.new
else
  { url: 'redis://redis.example.com:7372/12' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = redis
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = redis
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by mocking Redis for tagged RSpec tests in the `spec_helper.rb` file.

```
config.before(:each, redis: true) do
  mock = MockRedis.new
  allow(Redis).to receive(:new).and_return(mock)
end
```

Then in the scenario:

```
scenario "my scenario with redis", redis: true do
  ...
end
```